# 403 forbidden error on single route of laravel?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4, laravel-5

The code below gives me an error for mentioned routes

```
 Route::post('/new_blog_store', 'HoroscopeController@store');
```

How can I go about fixing this issue?

```
//blog section 
Route::get('/blog', 'HoroscopeController@blog');

Route::get('/blog_post', 'HoroscopeController@blog_post');

//show blog by id
Route::get('/blog_post/{id}', 'HoroscopeController@show');

//for blog login
//Route::get('/login', 'HoroscopeController@login');
//Route::get('/sign_up', 'HoroscopeController@sign_up');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

//middleware
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

   //for blog list page
   Route::get('/blog_list', ['as' => 'blog_list', 'uses' => 
  'HoroscopeController@blog_list']);

   //create new blog
   Route::get('/new_blog', 'HoroscopeController@new_blog');
   Route::post('/new_blog_store', 'HoroscopeController@store');


   //edit blog
   Route::get('/edit_blog/{id}', 'HoroscopeController@edit');
   //update blog
   Route::post('/update_blog/{id}', 'HoroscopeController@update_blog');

   //delete blog
   Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'HoroscopeController@destroy');
});

//end
```

Comment: Please fix your tags, what version are you really using? 4 or 5.2?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: And please remember that: there is a preview window: you can have a look how your question is formatted before submitting it. You want others to spend their time to help with your problem, so you should spent the 2 minutes it takes to come up with a properly formatted and indented question to us.

Comment: I am using laravel 5.4